# How can I delay my Arduino program to ensure the serial monitor is connected before proceeding?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I am trying to make a simple program to count how many characters are in a string and then print the number to the serial monitor. my problem is, I keep getting a weird output from the serial monitor. I have attached a screenshot of the output. [screenshot of serial monitor output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCyTv.png) I think that it is caused by the program running faster than the serial monitor can connect, because it only happens upon upload. if I reset the program, the problem disappears. how do I wait for the serial monitor to connect before proceeding with the rest of the program? I am using a Mega board, but would like it to be compatible with the uno if possible.

```
    const String str = "Hello, world"; // variable to hold our string

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // setup serial monitor
  delay(10);
}

void loop() {
 
  int charInMessage = 0; // variable to hold how long the string is

  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {charInMessage ++;} // count every char, and save it to the varialble

  Serial.println(charInMessage); // print the number of char in this string
 
  while(true); // stop the program so it only runs once

}
```

I tried adding a ten millisecond delay to void setup, hoping that it would give the serial monitor time to connect, but all it did was slightly decrease the number of unknown character boxes before the desired output.
Thank You!

Comment: what Arduino board?

Comment: Mega, but I want it to be compatible with uno (if possible)

Comment: it is always possible to get garbage at the start of the connection. it doesn't come from your sketch. the USB connection is handled by the USB chip of the Mega

Comment: So there is no way to ensure that the connection is stable before continuing with the program? Thank you for your time.